# Passing data to forms via URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a very basic bookmarklet.

My form exists on page, for example mysite.com/posts/, within a bootstrap modal box.

```
<div class="post-window">
    <div class="window-left">
        <textarea name="title_image" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Post title"></textarea> 
    <input name="postimage" class="form-control" placeholder="Post image URL" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-bottom">
    <div class="upload">
    <input type="hidden" name="letsbingo" value="1" />
        <button class="btn-block">Post Selfie</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

1- Following is bookmarklet code and it works fine.

```
javascript: var selfiesite = 'SelfieNow',
    selfiesiteurl = 'http://my.com/post/';
(function () {
    if (window.selfiesiteit !== undefined) {
        selfiesiteit();
    } else {
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src = 'http://my.com/assets/js/postit.js';
    }
})();
```

2- The result of above javascript is exactly what I want as shown below

```
http://my.com/post/?postimage=%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2013%2F12%2FGripster-Wrap-Mini-For-The-Ipad-Mini-3-690x460.jpg&title_image=Example%20-%20Men%27s%20Gear%2C%20Lifestyle%20and%20Trends
```

3- Now my my.com/post/ contians a piece of javascripts which triggers modal box on window load.

```
jQuery(window).load(function ($) {
    jQuery('#postModal').modal('show');
});
```

The bookmarklet is working, modal box is opening on window load. But data in not passing to form. The form opens in modal box, url changed but the form appears empty. I don't know what is wrong. Either the modal box is opening (on window load) the wrong way or the bookmarklet created url isn't fit for this kind of form. Please guide me a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind your `JS function` when the modal is show. Like this:

```
$('#postModal').on('show', function () {
    var selfiesite = 'SelfieNow',
    selfiesiteurl = 'http://my.com/post/';
    if (window.selfiesiteit !== undefined) {
        selfiesiteit();
    } else {
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src = 'http://my.com/assets/js/postit.js';
    }

});
```